# How to show a very heavy list on the site page by combobox in Asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a very heavy list of jobs And I want to display them in the Select2 plugin But when I open the registration form, the site becomes very heavy And the Select 2 plugin screen turns black and shows jobs after a few seconds.
I want the list not to be uploaded before the user searches for their job in Combobox.Please help me. Thank you

[image]

```
public IActionResult submitPerson()
{

  
    var Tamin = _context.TaminJobs.ToList();


    return View(Tamin);

}
```

```
    <label>شغل بیمه</label>
    <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" asp-for="@Model.person.SematYaShoghlBime">
        @foreach (var item in Model.TaminJobs)
        {
            <option value="@item.jobName @item.jobCode">@item.jobName @item.jobCode</option>
        }

    </select>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hi @sadegh farest, I cannot reproduce the issue by using your code. How many records of the jobs?  If your page only have one select without any other inputs, will the select2 plugin  turn black ?

Comment: i have 130000  records ,will the select2 plugin turn black and shows jobs after a few seconds.and the page  becomes very heavy Even if the plugin is only in the form.and I use public IEnumerable<TaminJobs> TaminJobs { get; set; }

Comment: Rena pleas help me?

Comment: Hi @sadegh farest, I suggest you try to use memory cache to store the records. Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0